# HTTP to HTTPS redirect not working in Apache+Varnish for WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, https, varnish

The issue I am facing is http to https redirect is not working. My current setup is varnish+apache. I am using apache to terminate SSL. Followed this guide (https://bash-prompt.net/guides/apache-varnish/) to do this (also followed "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS Error" part in that guide as I was getting the too many redirects error).
Varnish is running on port 80. Apache is running on port 8181 and terminating SSL. Tried adding redirect rules in htaccess but it is not working. Added the following lines to wp-config

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') {
   $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}

if ( !isset( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com' );
```

My current varnish vcl config:

```
vcl 4.0;

# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8181";
}

sub vcl_recv {

if (req.url ~ "wp-admin|wp-login") {

return (pass);

}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Happens after we have read the response headers from the backend.
    #
    # Here you clean the response headers, removing silly Set-Cookie headers
    # and other mistakes your backend does.
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Happens when we have all the pieces we need, and are about to send the
    # response to the client.
    #
    # You can do accounting or modifying the final object here.
}
```

My htaccess config:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "https" HTTPS=on
Header append Vary: X-Forwarded-Proto

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have literally tried almost every tutorial. Even tried redirecting HTTP to HTTPS via varnish vcl config itself but nothin seems to be working. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To Redirect all users from HTTP to HTTPS**

You can use any of the solutions below. You only need to use one or all three its up to you.

**1. PHP Solution**

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) != 'on') {
    header('Location: https://www.yourdomain.com');
    exit;
}
```

**2. Apache .htaccess solution**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

**3. Nginx Solution**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

**1. Varnish / Wordpress config - Manual setup solution**

https://betterprogramming.pub/set-up-varnish-cache-for-wordpress-8e2ac92ce347

**2. Varnish / Wordpress config - Wordpress plugin solution**

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/vcaching/

Comment: I have tried everything from the resources you mentioned above. Have u checked the guide which I followed for the Apache + Varnish setup?

Comment: Try disabling Nginx and Varnish to start with and only use apache and .htacess or the php method then if that works start from there and add nginx then varnish as i usually do, and let me know if that works. But test each of them at each stage, if you try them all at once you will end up going in circles as most of us do usually lol.

Comment: If you use the php redirect place it as the first lines inside public/index.php. With the .htaccess method you may find the virtualhost file has some options disabled stopping the .htaccess file redirects from working. Yet the php method should work fine regardless of the virtualhost file as long as it is at the start of the public/index.php

Comment: Also you can create a backup of your public/index.php and then create a new one and only place that code inside it, to test the php solution for sure. Just make sure with the php method you add the exit command as i wrote above or it will not always work.

Comment: For the .htaccess method to work you have to also make sure you have the mod rewrite plugin installed. On Linux the command is (sudo a2enmod rewrite) to install it then (sudo service apache2 restart) to ensure it is loaded the statement you have in your .htaccess (<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>) means it will only work if the rewrite extension is enabled or you will not see no error messages at all.

Comment: I think you should remove those first two lines in your .htaccess as well as i think they disable the http to https feature as they trick the server into believing it is already on https when it is still on http.

Comment: Well, a weird thing happened. I just updated my system using sudo apt-get upgraded and that fixed the problem (apache or varnish didnt have any updates)

Comment: @RahulBiswas Please add something to that effect as an answer and later accept it. I've just spent the last 15 mins pondering over your question (and reading the linked article) to finally read your comment that the problem is now fixed! :)

Comment: ok sure which comment was the best answer, please let me know and i will add it as a final solution

Comment: When you upgraded the system more likely apache updated. Your virtualhost file probably has settings inside it for the latest apache version like the line "AllowOverride All" or "Require all granted" which maybe inside your virtualhosts file which only really work on the latest version of apache, or they do not say any errors when you are using an old version yet do nothing for the older versions of apache, i have had this issue in the past. It is always a good idea to update apache, nginx and varnish to the latest versions before trying to config them.

Comment: As you will find many tutorials are written for the latest version of apache rather than any older versions these days or visa versa depending on the article. Between the old and new apache versions there are different virtual host file config options available you can use and which only work on one version of apache or the other. I had this problem a few times in the past, so i always remember to upgrade apache everytime these days.

Comment: The  "AllowOverride All" and "Require all granted" options inside the apache virtual host files allow for mod_rewrite to be enabled and work correctly. but only work on the lastest version of apache. The older versions of apache have different options settings which do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

For another php solution you can also use this at the start of your public/index.php
This should be alot more effective in your case

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) {
    header('Location: https://www.yourdomain.com');
    exit;
}

echo 'Your current server port is = '.$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'].'<br />';
```

Comment: And set the .htaccess to the wordpress default settings or delete it if its not needed for wordpress,